# How to handle parenthesis in grep?

Tags: bash, grep

`str` is of the following pattern:

```
1 abc (1 <something>)
```

For example:

```
1 abc (1 hello)
1 abc (1 shalom)
1 abc (1 hola)
```

How could I extract `<something>` from `str` using `egrep`?

Comment: RTFM http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html , keyword is "escape" .

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev there's more to it, he wants grep to print a specific group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to extract just the `<something>` then I'd suggest `grep -P` (perl regex):

```
grep -P -o '(?<=\(1 ).*?(?=\))' INPUTFILE
```

The `-o` returns just the matched portion being `<something>`. The regex looks for text preceded by `(1` and followed by `)`.

You wouldn't be able to do that with `egrep` as it doesn't support lookarounds. The best you'd do is extract the `(1 <something>)` with:

```
egrep -o '\(1 (.*)\)' INPUTFILE

[foo@bar ~]$ grep -P -o '(?<=\(1 ).*?(?=\))' INPUTFILE
hello
shalom
hola

[foo@bar ~]$ egrep -o '\(1 (.*)\)' INPUTFILE
(1 hello)
(1 shalom)
(1 hola)
```

Comment: What am I missing: grep -P -o '(?<=\(1 ).*?(?=\))' . fails with an "usage" complaint. I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.5

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use a simple `awk` one-liner for this.

```
awk -F"[ )]" '{print $(NF-1)}' filename
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat filename
1 abc (1 hello)
1 abc (1 shalom)
1 abc (1 hola)

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -F"[ )]" '{print $(NF-1)}' filename
hello
shalom
hola
```